# How to keep python program running until it is closed by user and python file handling

Tags: python, text, error-handling

So I want to create a program that takes input of some number of items and adds them to a text file. But I have encountered two problems. One, I don't know how to keep the program running until the user chooses to close it. Two, after the items are added to the text file and then displayed on the screen, it doesn't show the items in the correct order and some are even repeated and other left out. Below is my code, sorry if it's terrible I'm new to this. I had entered the letters s, i, c, and k, with each letter as an item and stored it to the text file and it returned this:

s

s

i

s

i

c

Here's my code

```
items = []
i= 0

ans = ""
print("Options:\n1: View existing items\n2: Add to list of items\n3: Clear saved items\n4: Make new list\n5. Exit program")
ans = input("\nWhat would you like to do?: ").strip()

if ans == "1":
        f = open("items.txt", "r")
        print(f.read())
        f.close
elif ans == "2":    
    i = int(input("How many items would you like to enter: ").lower())
    for i in range(i):
        item = input("Enter the name of item: ").lower()
        items.append(item)
        f =  open("items.txt", "a")
        for item in items:
            f.write(""+str(item)+"\n")
            f.close
elif ans == "3":
    f =  open("items.txt", "r+")
    f.truncate(0)
    f.close
elif ans == "4":
    i = int(input("How many items would you like to enter: ").lower())
    for i in range(i):
        item = input("Enter the name of item and price: ").lower()
        items.append(item)
        f =  open("items2.txt", "w")
        for item in items:
            f.write(""+str(item)+"\n")
        f.close
elif ans == "5":
    quit()
else:
    print("Choose by entering either 1, 2, 3 or 4.")
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a file?

Comment: Sure. I had entered the letters s, i, c, and k, with each letter as an item and stored it to the text file and when I read it, it said this:

s

s

i

s

i

c

Answer (score 0):

You'd do something like this:

```
# to write to a file
number_of_inputs = int(input("How many lines would you like to enter? "))
with open("inputs.txt", "w") as file:
    for i in range(number_of_inputs):
        file.write(
            input("What would you like to write on line %s? " % (i)) 
            + "\n"
        )

# to read from the file 
with open("inputs.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        print(line)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I was really struggling

Comment: I'll try it out and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

I've come to this :

```
items = []
i = 0
leave = False

while leave is False:
    print("Options:\n"
          "1: View existing items\n"
          "2: Add to list of items\n"
          "3: Clear saved items\n"
          "4: Make new list\n"
          "5. Exit program\n")

ans = input("What would you like to do ? ").strip()

if ans == "1":
    with open("items.txt", "r") as f:
        print(f.read())
elif ans == "2":
    i = int(input("How many items would you like to enter : "))

    items = [input("Enter the name of item : ").lower() for i in range(i)]

    with open("items.txt", "a") as f:
        for item in items:
            f.write("{}\n".format(item))
elif ans == "3":
    with open("items.txt", "r+") as f:
        f.truncate(0)
elif ans == "4":
    i = int(input("How many items would you like to enter: ").lower())

    items = [input("Enter the name of item and price: ").lower() for i in range(i)]

    with open("items2.txt", "w") as f:
        for item in items:
            f.write("{}\n".format(item))
elif ans == "5":
    leave = True
else:
    print("Choose by entering either 1, 2, 3 or 4.")
```

To keep the program running until the user choose to close it you can use a `while` loop with a `leave` variable which takes the value `True` in case the user decides to quit the program by answering 5.
To open your files you should use the `with` statement.
That code works but it's not perfect because it does not give the user the choice to choose which file (list) to read and show on the screen so you can only have one list. To make it possible for the user to choose between the files you should use the `os` module.

Which brings us to that code :

```
import os

os.chdir("itemsFolder")

items = []
i = 0
leave = False

while leave is False:
print("Options:\n"
      "1: View existing items\n"
      "2: Add to list of items\n"
      "3: Clear saved items\n"
      "4: Make new list\n"
      "5. Exit program\n")

ans = input("What would you like to do ? ").strip()

if ans == "1":
    fileName = input("Which list would you like to consult : {} ".format(os.listdir()))

    if os.path.exists(fileName):
        with open(fileName, "r") as f:
            print(f.read())
    else:
        print("No such list of item exists.")
elif ans == "2":
    fileName = input("Which list would you like to consult : {} ".format(os.listdir()))

    if os.path.exists(fileName):
        i = int(input("How many items would you like to enter : "))

        items = [input("Enter the name of item : ").lower() for i in range(i)]

        with open(fileName, "a") as f:
            for item in items:
                f.write("{}\n".format(item))
    else:
        print("No such list of item exists.")
elif ans == "3":
    fileName = input("Which list of items would you like to clear : {} ".format(os.listdir()))

    if os.path.exists(fileName):
        with open(fileName, "r+") as f:
            f.truncate(0)
    else:
        print("No such list of item exists.")
elif ans == "4":
    fileName = input("What do you want to call your new list : ").lower()

    i = int(input("How many items would you like to enter: ").lower())

    items = [input("Enter the name of item and price: ").lower() for i in range(i)]

    with open(fileName + '.txt', "w") as f:
        for item in items:
            f.write("{}\n".format(item))
elif ans == "5":
    leave = True
else:
    print("Choose by entering either 1, 2, 3 or 4.")
```

You should use this tree structure in your project to use the code above :

ProjectFolder
|
-main.py
-itemsFolder

Comment: Whoa. Thanks a ton, I'll try to be better, this really helps.

Comment: I'll try it out and see what happens